# DataTable is not a member of DataSet

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, visual-studio-2005, member

Well, this may look an stupid question but I've been pulling my hair out all morning with this.

In my VS 2005 project, i've already created a fully working DataSet with a lot of DataTables. Due to new requirements in the project I need to create a few new DataTables into my DataSet. Once created, i'm facing a problem i've never seen before. I'm unable to use the new DataTable into the existing DataSet.

```
Dim ds as new ExistingDataSet
```

I can use the already created old data structure

```
ds.ExistingTable.ExistingColumn 'No problems
```

But when I try to use the new created DataTable with `ds.NewDataTable.NewColumn` VS shows an error: `NewTable is not a member of ExistingDataSet`

I have checked that my new DataTable and its own columns appears at Data Sources window, tried to clean and rebuild the project and so on...
The funny thing is that in order to isolate the problem (which i think resides somewhere into the DataSet designer definition) i've done a test, just creating a new DataSet with a new DataTable. This way i can use it without problems

```
Dim dsTest as New DataSetTEST
dsTest.DataTable1.Column1
```

I know i could create a new DataSet with the same structure as the old one plus the new datatable, and replace the old non-working dataset with this new one, but my old Dataset is already linked with some reports and I'd like to use my existing dataset with my new data and avoid having to replace all the data links again.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Where did you add the new DataTables to your ExistingDataSet?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that i added the new DataTable at DataSet designer window.

Comment: Then try to check the dataset `.Designer` file to see how it is defined there. Maybe it's private instead of public

Comment: Thanks for the clue @Pikoh, it's defined as `Partial Public Class ExistingDataSet`. The datatables are all (old ones and new one) defined as `Private`

Comment: You should have something like `public NewDataTableDataTable  NewDataTable {
            get {
                return this.table NewDataTable;
            }
        }`

Comment: There is a subtle bug in VS that under certain circs it seems to lose sync between the designer and the generated code for datasets. Try rt-clicking the .xsd file in the solution explorer and select 'properties'. Make sure Custom Tool is set to MSDataSetGenerator.

Comment: @peterG You rocks!! That's it!! I would never have solved it myself. Please     answer the question so i can accept it and upvote. Thanks you also Pikoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle (and long-standing) bug in VS that under certain circs it seems to lose sync between the designer and the generated code for datasets. Try rt-clicking the .xsd file in the solution explorer and select 'properties'. Make sure Custom Tool is set to MSDataSetGenerator.